# Prevent files from being processed multiple times in AWS Glue

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, etl, aws-glue

We are using glue for computing purposes. The data flow is happening like this `landing->raw->stage->curated->Redshift`.

However, when the everyday the data flows right -> the data is exactly getting doubled.

For example:

- Aug 1: I have 100 records
- Aug 2: I have 20 records

In Redshift, I would like to see 120 records at end of August 2. Instead of that, it is getting 220 records. Please refer me to a way to avoid this scenario.

Would like to retain partition based on the run date in both raw and stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to track files that have already been processed. You can prevent that by using the [job bookmarking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) feature of Glue.